# Xcode 4 - "Archive" is greyed out?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I would like to archive my application, but the Archive option is greyed out. What could cause this?

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you change "Skip Install" in your target to NO

Comment: Basically, at the top left select "iOS Device", NOT a simulator.

Comment: Select "Generic ios device"

Answer (score 971, accepted):

You have to select the device in the schemes menu in the top left where you used to select between simulator/device. It won’t let you archive a build for the simulator.

Or you may find that if the iOS device is already selected the archive box isn’t selected when you choose “Edit Schemes” => “Build”.

Comment: Doesn't it seem like that drop down indicates where you want to run the app? Seems like a silly restriction to prevent archiving when a simulator is selected...

Comment: Note that in XCode 8.2 the menu item to select is now called "Generic iOS Device". For a minute I thought this answer was saying to select a physical iOS device.

Answer (score 49):

see the picture. but I have to type enough chars to post the picture.:)

[image]

Answer (score 22):

As the other answers state, you need to select an active scheme to something that is not a simulator, i.e. a device that's connected to your mac.

**If you have no device connected to the mac then selecting "Generic IOS Device" works also.**

[image]

Image for newer versions of XCode:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this today...sort of.  Although the archives still don't show up anywhere.  But I got the Archive option back by going into Build Settings for the project and re-assigning my certs under "Code Signing Identity" for each build.  They seemed to have gotten reset to something else when imported my 3.X project to 4.

I also used the instructions found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH11-DontLinkElementID_69

But I still can't get the actual archives to show up in Organizer (even though the files exist)

Comment: Maybe this helps you. You can tickmark "Reveal Archive in Organizer" here: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Archive > Options