# Xcode4 - Build for Archiving greyed out

Tags: iphone, xcode, submit, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4 - “Archive” is greyed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out)

I want to submit my iOS App via Xcode 4. The problem is that I cant do the Build for Archiving. Its Inactive and Gray (the Menu Item Product->Build For->Build For Archiving) and i dont know why.

Anybody an Idea?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In the scheme drop down you have to choose an actual device, not one of the simulators.

Comment: I would have preferred an error dialog than this mysterious greying out. I'm definitely not fond of certain design choices from Apple in Xcode...