# XCode 4 and App submission process

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store

I have very little experience of submitting iPhone Apps and even that was on the older XCode 3.2

I have now created an app, which is working fine on Simulator (iPhone/iPad). Now the next step is that I want to submit it to the App Store.

I would like to understand the "complete" process for submission. I know there are a lot of changes after XCode 4, but would not just like to understand what is different, but a step-by-step guide.

I have read some documentation on Apple IOS portal and the one on
http://surgeworks.com/blog/lab-mobile/iphone/how-to-build-and-submit-a-universal-app-for-distribution-on-the-app-store-with-the-ios-4-sdk

But that has left me even more confused...The information that I am looking for includes;
Whether the Certificate/App IDs/Provisioning Profile, etc still need to be created ? If yes, how ?
In my XCode, the "Archive" option is grayed out ? So when will that get enabled ?
What is the overall role in Organizer now ?

Please provide your answers in an easy language..

Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think app submission is a valid question .

Comment: This is too broad of a question.  You should ask one question at a time. Some of your questions already have answers that you can search for, such as: [why Archive is greyed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5267479/154803).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is overly broad, but I will give you a broad answer...

1) Yes you still have to make an app store distribution certificate.

2) Archive is greyed out because you have not selected "build for device" instead of the simulator.  Select that, run Archive, then click on the archive when it finishes.  Go to the portal and create a new release for your app, then it will be ready for upload.   Now go back to XCode, select the archive you built and tell it to submit to the app store.

The process now is super simple, since it checks everything for you and submits from XCode.

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial its great

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THKpJrMu204