# GEOJson file greyed on selection from Xcode

Tags: xcode, geojson, ios6-maps

Hullo,
I would like to test my app for the turn-by-turn configuration and so I wanted to load my GEOJson file to Xcode. Yet when I open the Routing App Coverage File pulldown and try to select my polygon it appears greyed, like all other documents in my filesystem, for that matter. Should it have some specific form or ending, or what else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the file with another xcode project? I've had issues with XCode project files in the past and have had to re-create the project or completely remove all my resources and add them back in to update the directory references.

Comment: Actually that project was brand new as I had to rebuild it due to problems in the old project file. So I do not think doing it after two days again would change things so much. Anyway I just tried the same thing on another project and all files are still disabled.

Comment: Is it a case of they are only enabled if a specific project template is selected? Maybe try their solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out i know its an entirely different problem but ya never know. I wish i has my xcode and mac at hand so i could re create what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get XCode to find the file either .. but I renamed the file to `GeoJSON` without any file extension and then ran my app through the Simulator without first associating it to my Scheme as described by the Apple docs. And that worked.

For reference my `GeoJSON` file contained Denmark e.g.

```
{
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                [
                    6.592041015625,
                    58.029833609102994
                ],
                [
                    13.952880859375,
                    57.924973963067735
                ],
                [
                    13.886962890625,
                    52.89389531877394
                ],
                [
                    5.910888671875,
                    53.21087169635909
                ],
                [
                    6.592041015625,
                    58.029833609102994
                ],
                [
                    6.592041015625,
                    58.029833609102994
                ],
                [
                    6.592041015625,
                    58.029833609102994
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by appending the right file ending by trying to upload the file on iTunes connect and receiving a tale-telling error.