# ios build for archive in Xcode 4 with no device

Tags: xcode, build, archiving

I created the `adhoc` provisioning files with a friend's device id and when someone else built the app, my friend was able to run it on their iPhone.

I don't own an iphone myself. Now I am trying to build it and upload it to iTunes. Since I don't have the actual device I followed advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out) because it the `build for archive` option was grayed out.

I selected iOS device and the build for archive option became available but the build fails, even though it works fine on the emulator.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Note**: In code signing I chose `iPhone distribution`

Comment: What is the build error?

Answer (score 0):

Archive builds the **Relese** configuration where running in the simulator builds the **Debug** configuration. You need a development and release code signing certificate and development and release provisioning profiles. Every time you update a provisioning profile you need to refresh your provisioning profile library in the Xcode Organizer.