# Can't archive with cocoapods Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So I have been using cocoapods recently, and it works in the simulator. All my libraries link fine. All my files are being referenced fine in the code and I am not getting any errors. However, for some reason "Archive" is grayed out and I can't archive my app. Since I don't have any error codes... I can't provide any code for you guys, but if you need things I can post them. I don't know why at this point this isn't working. Any and all tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever try to switch to real device instead of Simulator? Because archive button only available when you build on real device.

Reference:
[Xcode 4 - "Archive" is greyed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out)

Comment: Yup... feeling like an idiot right about now. Thanks!