# Using my device as an Emulator: "Archive" button is greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I am trying to create an IPA from my device (Iphone app) that was written in XCode. While doing so I encountered a little problem, "product -> archive" is grey and blocked.

As I saw in [Xcode 4 - "Archive" is greyed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out) in the top bar after the play/stop btn there should be: "project name > iOS device" to allow to iPA the project ([press here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc39L.png)), but i don't find such an option on my mac!?

If this might help to answer my question i should say that I do have an option to select "Generic iOS Device" but then I have an error while building "No code signing identities"

I will be very happy for help :)

Thanks,

Tomer

Comment: Make sure you have the developer certificates and provisioning profiles to archive your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Generic iOS Device" is the correct option to do an archive. If you dont have any code signing identities, go to the Xcode preferences account tab, and add your apple developer account. You may have to make a provisioning profile for your app

Comment: Thanks Fonix,
how do I get to my "Xcode preferences account tab"?